# How to write rows to Kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a data frame that has 4 columns, I want to push each row as an event to Kafka.

1. one way to push the event to Kafka

```
df = df.selectExpr("CAST(id AS STRING) as key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value");

df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
        .write()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        .option("topic", "test")
        .save();
```

**Concern**:

- I think this doesn't provide a callback(that event is being pushed or not) and another thing we don't have a dto/models to share with the consumer using that they can deserialize the class object.

2. Another way to push event to Kafka

For each row of data frame call a UDF/method which create a class object using that 4 columns and serialize with let's say `serializedClassObject = mapper.writeValueAsString(classObj)` and call Kafka producer's `producer.send(serializedClassObject,new Callback() { <callback implementation> });`

**Concerns** :

- Is this second way is slower as compared to the first way as we may be pushing events one by one not as a batch.

I wanted to know with which implementation should I go, I am kind of inclined toward 2nd way because of the sharable event model and callback but I am not sure about a batch push to Kafka.

Comment: `mapper.writeValueAsString` should be the same as `to_json(struct(*))`

Comment: @AlexOtt yes, it's the same, but in this case, I won't be having model/DTOs to share with consumer clients (means I can create a model by looking at df column but I didn't use this anywhere serialize so some issue might come in future).

Answer (score 0):

> I think this doesn't provide a callback(that event is being pushed or not)

It does and when it fails it gives you an exception (to be caught by a Spark application itself).

> Another way to push event to Kafka

Use [Dataset.foreach](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#foreach(f:T=%3EUnit):Unit) or [Dataset.foreachPartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#foreachPartition(f:Iterator%5BT%5D=%3EUnit):Unit).

```
foreach(f: (T) ⇒ Unit): Unit

foreachPartition(f: (Iterator[T]) ⇒ Unit): Unit
```